# My first project stuck on OnActivityforResult

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onactivityresult, onbackpressed

I tried to make a simple app which can keep scores on a game with four players. When I press the plus or minus button it opens a new activity (dialog theme) where the user should enter their score. That score should be stored into a text view.

Some part of code looks like this:

Here I opened new activities

```
        buttonPlus1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonPlus2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonPlus3.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonPlus4.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonMinus1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.buttPlusPlayer1:

                    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                    break;

                case R.id.buttPlusPlayer2:
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(this, ThirdPlusActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i2, 2);
                    break;

                case R.id.buttPlusPlayer3:
                    Intent i3 = new Intent(this, FourthPlusActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i3, 3);
                    break;

                case R.id.buttPlusPlayer4:
                    Intent i4 = new Intent(this, FifthPlusActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i4, 4);
                    break;

                case R.id.buttMinusPlayer1:
                    Intent i5 = new Intent(this, FirstMinusActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i5, 1);
            }
            }
```

That's an example how activities send data back to main activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEditText;
    private ImageButton mBackSpace;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        setTitle("ADD POINTS");
        mEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTxtActivity);



        //implementing backspace button

        mBackSpace = findViewById(R.id.backSpaceButton);
        mBackSpace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str = mEditText.getText().toString();
                if (str.length() > 0) {
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
                    mEditText.setText(str);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("message", mEditText.getText().toString());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                Toast.makeText(this, "You added " + mEditText.getText().toString() + " points", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            }
    }
```

and "now" I receive the results from activities

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)   {
        String a = data.getStringExtra("message");
        int i =Integer.parseInt(a);
        String b = data.getStringExtra ("message5");
        int z = Integer.parseInt(b);
        Integer fResult = i - z;
        String firstResult = fResult.toString();
        mFirstScore.setText(firstResult);
            }

        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mSecondscore.setText(data.getStringExtra("message2"));
        }
        if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mThirdScore.setText(data.getStringExtra("message3"));
        }

        if (requestCode == 4 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mFourthscore.setText(data.getStringExtra("message4"));
        }
```

the problem is on the last part of the code because I don't know how to receive data from activities and to calculate the result. I want when the user hit the plus button to add numbers and when minusButton is clicked to substract and the result to be stored on a TextView which, for player1, in my case is mFirstScore.
Is this possible or I did everything wrong and it is not possible to manipulate data received from another activity how I image

PS: on **case** buttMinusPlayer1 and on first **if** with **requestCode 1** I've tried something ;

Comment: Make a single interface and implement in all activities ,rather using activityForResult

Answer (score 2):

On SecondActivity put your key `message2`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("message2", mEditText.getText().toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();       
}
```

and get the data from SecondActivity by the same key `message2`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        mSecondscore.setText(data.getStringExtra("message2"));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.